# R - Match a value from one data frame with multiple values from another

Tags: r, dataframe

For example, say I have the two data frames...

```
d1 <- data.frame(c(a,b,c,d,e,f))
d2 <- data.frame(c(a,a,a,b,b,d,d,d,d,d,e,e,f))
```

And I want to search 'a' from d1 in d2 and reveal the index of every matching value, which can be stored in a vector.

I've searched for and played around with the Match() function, but this only seems to work when there is just one matching value.

Thanks

Comment: What would be the desired output from your example data?

Comment: Unless those letters are objects, they need to be quoted, and you should probably also give the variables names so they don't end up gross. Also, you're looking for the [data.frame] tag, not [dataframes].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a value from one data frame with multiple values from another, you could loop through the first data.frame and get the indice in the second for each value.

```
d1 <- data.frame(x = c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), stringsAsFactors = F)
d2 <- data.frame(x = c("a","a","a","b","b","d","d","d","d","d","e","e","f"), stringsAsFactors = F)

sapply(d1$x, function(value) which(d2 == value))
#> $a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 4 5
#> 
#> $c
#> integer(0)
#> 
#> $d
#> [1]  6  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> $e
#> [1] 11 12
#> 
#> $f
#> [1] 13
```

Comment: which(d2 == value)) is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.